# Не могу добавить dockerfile в проект

Tags: c#, visual-studio

При попытке добавить поддержку Docker в проект получаю такое сообщение:
[image: ошибка из студии]

Может ли это быть из-за того, что проект ссылается на другие сборки, которые находятся в других папках? Т.е. мой проект тут (для примера): `D:\vs\MyProj\MyProj.sln` (csproj в `D:\vs\MyProj\Backend\MyProjApi\MyProjApi.csproj`), а ссылается на `D:\vs\Test\MyTestProj\MyTestProj.csproj`

Может ли из-за этого не добавляться docker? Если да, то как обходить эту ситуацию, потому что одни и те же проекты используются в нескольких проектах и не хотелось бы городить костыли.

Comment: Ну да, test вам надо переложить, очевидно же. Солюшн не должен быть отдельно от проекта.

Comment: @aepot и как мне быть если test используется в 5 проектах одновременно? Это несколько общих сборок для разных проектов, дублировать код абсолютно нет желания :(

Comment: Ну вы для начала попробуйте, в этом ли проблема. С моей точки зрения это тоже странно.

Comment: @aepot только что буквально попробовал - в этом. Если нет посторонних проектов из других папок - всё ок, добавляю - ошибка. Ничего странного нет, те же всякие расширения LINQ и прочего в общей сборке для всех проектов

Comment: Симлинк можно попробовать. Можно ещё попробовать перевести завистмость на рантайм, то есть не через сорц ссылаться, а dll-ку подкладывать, по аналогии с нугетом.

Comment: @aepot Можно небольшой пример, как это будет для моего случая? К тому же docker стоит на другой машине, а не на моей (и на моей тоже, но работать будет на другой машине)

Comment: Симлинк - виртуальная папка, ссылающаяся на другое место на диске.

Comment: @OwDafuq проект может и правда лежать где угодно при сборке классическими средствами. Но если вы пытаетесь собрать его в докере - возникает проблема: докер клиент перед самой сборкой формирует так называемый docker context и передаёт его серверу докера, и вся дальнейшая сборка может обращаться только к файлам из этого самого docker context. docker context обязан быть одной папкой.

Comment: @OwDafuq попробуйте перед освоением докера положить свой проект хотя бы в гит, так чтобы его можно было без приключений скачать на другом компьютере и собрать. Для подключения общих проектов вам подойдут сабмодули или nuget пакеты. А там и докер подключить получится (концептуально, докер образ мало чем отличается от другого компьютера)

Comment: Ссылки: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8, https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: @PavelMayorov С гитом никаких проблем нет, в организации его и используем, просто встал вопрос докера в один момент. Правильно понимаю, что если я сделаю свой локальный Nuget, то потом могу его добавить в Dockerfile по типу `RUN dotnet nuget add source server\\Nuget
RUN dotnet restore "TestApi/TestApi.csproj"`? Где server\\Nuget - расшаренная папка с windows server'a

Comment: @OwDafuq не уверен что на линуксе такое сработает без установленной Samba, а её в докерфайлах вам скорее всего тоже придётся ставить. Однако, есть куча нормальных реализаций репозитория nuget, начиная с бесплатного gitlab

Comment: @PavelMayorov git submodules работают как надо, можете написать ответом - отмечу.